# Check up all Checkbox using Javascript and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

```
if (this.checked != true) {
  this.checked = true;
}    
else {
  this.checked = false;
}
```

Above code enables `Check up All` and `Check out All` function. However, I found that if any of check box is reversely checked by user, every output reverses.

How should I change in order to acheive followings when `button` is clicked?

1. Check Up All box (Acheive)
2. check Up any box that isn't checked **(Problem)**
3. Check Out every box when `all` boxes are checked (Acheive)

Belows is the full code:

```
function display() {
  $.ajax({
     url: "test.php",
     type: "get",
     data: {
              a: $('#selectest option:selected').val()
           }
         }).done(function(data) {
                    $('#result').text(data);
                    alert("Checking test");

                    $('input:checkbox[class='+data+']').each(function() {
                      if(this.checked != true){
                      this.checked = true;
                        }

                      else{
                        this.checked = false;
                        }
                    });
                  });
                }
```

Comment: It appears that you want to use a SINGLE button to do both check all and un-check all. But if the user has already checked "half" of the checkboxes, what happens ? - So the solution I can think of is simply use two separate buttons, one is "Check-all" and the other one is "Uncheck all".

Comment: @KenLee That is the exact problem. Is implementing those function into Single button impossible?

Comment: Actually it is possible : (1) first check how many checkboxes are already "checked", (2), if the number of checkboxes checked is MORE or EQUAL to the number of checkboxes unchecked, then uncheck ALL the checkboxes , else check all the checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Was the user name `Undefined` actually available, or did you find a glitch in the matrix?

Your question contradicts your code. This answer is for your question. Your code appears to be setting checkbox states from an ajax call, which is something entirely different.

Since you're using jQuery, you can use the [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector. Then you can just check if the number of checked checkboxes is equal to the total number of checkboxes, and toggle `.prop('checked')` accordingly.

In this snippet, if all checkboxes are checked, all checkboxes will be unchecked (item 3). If not all checkboxes are checked, all checkboxes will be checked (item 1 and 2).

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length !==
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').length
  );
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<button>toggle</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```